# Langrange Multiplier, to find maximum volume of a cone

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

**Question:** A right-angled triangle is rotated about one of its sides that form the right angle to a cone. Given that the sum of the lengths of two sides of the triangle that form the right angle is $P$, find these lengths that would maximize the volume of the cone.

**My attempt:**

I know there must be a use of langrange multipliers but I am not too sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The volume of the cone is $\pi r^2 h/3$ where $h$ is the height and $r$ is the radius.  We also know that $r + h = P$, which leads to the constraint $r + h - P = 0$.

So the expression for which to find extrema is:

$$F(r, h, \lambda) = \frac{\pi r^2 h}{3} - \lambda(r+h-P).$$

Taking the partials with respect to $r, h, \lambda$ and setting each equal to zero should lead you to $h = P/3$ and $r = 2P/3.$

Comment: Wouldn't $r+h-P=0$?

Comment: That's exactly right.

Comment: Also why would you want to minimize this, is this equivalent to maximising $F(r, h, \lambda) = \frac{\pi r^2 h}{3} + \lambda(r+h-P).$? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Right.  Taking partial derivatives of $F$ with respect to $r,h,$ and $\lambda$ give you three equations that lead to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use Lagrange? The volume of a cone is given by $$V=\frac 1 3 \pi r^2 h.$$

You are given that $r+h=P$ and you need to maximize $V$ given this restriction. Because you are not given any real values for the restriction, your answer will be expressed in terms of $P$. Put $h=P-r$ into the equation for the volume above:
$$V=\frac 1 3 \pi r^2(P-r)$$ and differentiate $V$ with respect to $r$, setting it equal to $0$ to find the maximum point.